# match a character sequence in a word

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to create a generic model to find the occurence ofa a particular sequence of characters inside a word, I was able to find the occurence of specif input.. but I want to generalise this expression.. Here is only calculates the occurence of "in" inside the words.. I want to generalize the regular expression so that it will compare the  occurance of any input that I provide can this be done using regex in javascript?

I will add a sample fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2BAFG/

Comment: heheh - four independent & near identical answers imply a workable solution :p

Answer (score 1):

You can create regex from string:

```
var regex = new RegExp( $('#yourinput').val(), "i");
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2BAFG/6/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var matches = function(m) {
    var re = new RegExp(m, "i");
    return data.filter(function(item) { return re.test(item) });
};

document.write(matches('in'));
```

example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2BAFG/8/

the substring to find is now passed as argument of a function

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can construct a regex from an arbitrary string using `new RegExp()` and use that instead.

So instead of:

```
var matches = data.filter(function(item) { return /in/i.test(item) });
```

You can use:

```
var re = new RegExp("in", "i");
var matches = data.filter(function(item) { return re.test(item) });
```

Where `"in"` can be any regex string you like, including one that is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe so, yes.

In your fiddle, you have

```
var matches = data.filter(function(item) { return /in/i.test(item) });
```

try changing it to

```
var inputToMatch = "in";
var patt=new RegExp(inputToMatch,"i");
var matches = data.filter(function(item) { return patt.test(item) });
```

Comment: how do I make it case insensitive

Comment: the second parameter to 'RexExp' ("i" in the example) should make it insensitive (same as /in/i does)